# WCF prevent concurrent background tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, concurrency

I am developing a WCF web service that is set up like this:

1. Web method that is periodically triggered (every 15 minutes) by REST requests from a task scheduler.
2. When triggered, web method starts a background method using Task.Factory.StartNew. This method involves getting and posting to and from remote APIs and writing to a local database, and sometimes takes several minutes to complete.
3. As soon as the background method has started, the web method returns a "successfully triggered" message and terminates.

My question is this: will the background method be able to run concurrently on multiple threads if the web method is triggered again while it is still running? I DO NOT want this to happen, as it could cause all sorts of trouble. Ideally I would want multiple calls to queue up and be executed one-by-one on a single background thread.

I'm not sure if Task.Factory.StartNew is the best way to do this either, would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TaskFactory.StartNew`, if you create a `TaskFactory` with the right kind of `TaskScheduler`...

I suggest grabbing the Parallel Extensions Extras [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) and using the [OrderedTaskScheduler](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=154682735) to run your tasks:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Schedulers.OrderedTaskScheduler sch = new OrderedTaskScheduler();

//you could persist this as static or in the kernel of your favorite DI framework    
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(sch); 

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var x = i;
    //these Console operations will occur in order
    taskFactory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine(x));
    //but if we did as below, order would be lost
    //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

So, you can see, it runs the actions in a single thread in the order that they were added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the WCF service itself to limit execution to a single thread at a time (I.e. concurrent calls to the service will block and execute one at a time) consider using the following properties of the ServiceBehaviorAttribute you can attach to your service implementation.

InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx

ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode(v=vs.110).aspx